# Error when trying to install extention locally by direct package file upload

Tags: extensions, magento-connect, magento-connect-manager

I have a working copy of magento locally. I'm trying to install extension directly to that system. But it gives "no file was uploaded" error. Has anyone encountered similar issue? I have not faced this problem when I install same file online.

Comment: check the var folder permission..

Comment: maybe the file size is over the max upload size

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and managed to fix it by commenting out the rewrite instructions in my main `.htaccess` file in Magento's root folder. Don't forget to add those instructions back after you finished installing your module.

I suggest you keep a `.htaccess.magento-connect` file for when you want to use Magento Connect along with your regular `.htaccess` file, and switch between the two.